# My laptop not turning on after pressing enter it turns on

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

my laptop not power on it only turns on when I keeps pressing enter key it turns on perfectly but when i release it shows turn off pannel immediatelly and turns off automitacally after some time. My laptop is new it has only complated only 1 months please help me. I tried to restore BIOS setup i tried to update input driver via command then also same problem please help me sir

Comment: It probably is still under warranty. So I would return it to the vendor.

Comment: yes it is in warrenty